# Can I save a graph with its values without saving the inputs?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a network with weights filled by manual `tf.assign`, and now I want to save the network with the weight values but without the placeholder inputs. It seems `tf.train.Saver` works only when I have the `feed_dict` available, and `tf.train.export_meta_graph` only saves the network structure. I tried `pickle` and `dill` but they both have errors. Are there any better solutions for this kind of saving?

Answer (score 0):

Placeholders convert the input data into Tensors so I guess they are an important part of the Graph and I don't understand why you don't want to include them.

Even if you use tf.assign, you can freeze the graph, which means combining the structure with the weights. What freezing does is to convert Tensorflow variables into constants.

You have to save the structure of your graph:

```
gdef = g.as_graph_def()
tf.train.write_graph(gdef,".","graph.pb",False)
```

Then save the weights (after training)

```
saver.save(sess, 'tmp/my-weights')
```

And freeze the graph according to the tutorial in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite

After that, you can use the Graph.

Comment: For the reason: I was thinking about saving the graph structure with some externally pretrained weights, and doing inference with different data sources (where the inputs are of the same shape). If I have to save the inputs it seems that I have to save duplicated versions of the model.

Comment: Indeed, but when you are saving the weights this time they will be saved in an appropriate format to later freeze the graph and have it all in one single file you can use later. I'm not sure if you already have the weights in another format but in order to merge them with the graph I guess they need to be in that format saved with the Saver.

Comment: I am converting a pretrained network in custom JSON format to Tensorflow, so I construct the network in TensorFlow, assign the weight values with `tf.assign`, and now want to save the network at this stage. If I have to use `Saver` that is fine.